# R function decorator for data base connection

Tags: r, decorator

I want to write function decorator in R to make a data base connection. I red basic steps on writing decorators in R [The Weak Learner Decorators in R](http://weinstockj.github.io/blog/2016/06/08/decorators-in-r/). The examples in this post work fine.

To connect to database I have to pass an argument `data_base_name` inside decorator itself, which gives me an error message: `Error in eval(parse(text = text, keep.source = FALSE), envir) : object 'data_base_name' not found`

My decorator function:

```
    db_connect_decorator<-function(f) {
    function(...) {
        loginfo(str_glue("connecting to {data_base_name}"))
        for(i in 1:5){
        bSuccess=F
        tryCatch({
            con = dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(), 
                            user=Sys.getenv("DB_USER"), 
                            password=Sys.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"), 
                            dbname=data_base_name, 
                            host=Sys.getenv("DB_HOST"),
                            port=Sys.getenv("DB_PORT") %>% as.integer())
            bSuccess=T
        }, error = function(e) {
            logerror(str_c("Error connecting data base: ", e, "trying to reconnect", sep = " "))
            Sys.sleep(1)
        })
        if(bSuccess) {
            assert(dbIsValid(con))
            Sys.sleep(1)
            result = f(con, ...)  
            assert(dbDisconnect(con))
            return(result)
        }else{
            logerror("Failed to connect to database")
            return(NULL)
        }
        }
    }
    }
```

Wrapper for decorator as described in tutorial (works fine without additional arguments):

```
    `%@%` = function(`@`, f) {
    `@`(f)
    }
```

Function to work with data base, contains data base name:

```
    db_download<-db_connect_decorator %@% function(data_base_name, con=NULL){
    db_rs = dbSendQuery(con, "select * from my_table")
    res<<-fetch(db_rs, n=-1)
    dbClearResult(db_rs)
    res    
    }
```

This code gives me error:

```
    db_download("mydb")
```

How to pass additional variable into decorator function in R, or some workaround?

Comment: What was it tagged as `python`?

Comment: I want decorators like in python, so I added this tag. It will help to find the write answer

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer by myself. This is universal approach, but I show it use on data base query example.

It is necessary to convert ellipsis arguments to `R` `list` in function call all arguments must be named. Here is my solution:

```
    fdecorator<-function(f, ...) {
        function(...) {
        kargs<-list(...)
        print(kargs$data_base_name)
        tryCatch({
            con= dbConnect(RMySQL::MySQL(),
                        user=Sys.getenv("DB_USER"),
                        password=Sys.getenv("DB_PASSWORD"),
                        dbname=kargs$data_base_name,
                        host=Sys.getenv("DB_HOST"),
                        port=Sys.getenv("DB_PORT") %>% as.integer())
            f(con, ...)
            dbDisconnect(con)
        }, error = function(e) {
            logerror(str_glue("Error connecting data base: {e}"))
        })
        }
    }
    f<-function(con, ...){
        kargs<-list(...)
        print(str_glue("Querying data base {kargs$data_base_name}"))
        # query database
    }
    fdecorated<-fdecorator(f)
    fdecorated(data_base_name="my_db")
```